# Why the same font size for different latex sections with Auctex when `font-latex-fontify-sectioning` is a float?

Tags: latex, auctex, fonts

As far as I understand, setting `font-latex-fontify-sectioning` to a number larger than 1.0 should make it so that the titles of sections of different levels have different sizes.

However, even though I set this variable to 3.5 as in:

```lisp
(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 3.5) ;; headers with larger font
```

This is still not working. Instead, their fonts have different colors, not different sizes, as if this variable was set to `color`.

Why am I getting the same font size?

---

EDIT/UPDATE:

Since I asked this question I managed to find the main issue: I had a hook activating `TeX-fold-mode` which seems to override the section face set by `font-latex-fontify-sectioning`. I also had a hook running `outline-hide-body`, but this does not seem to interfere with `font-latex-fontify-secitoning`.

If instead of running these with the hook I run this function interactively, all goes well:

```lisp
(defun latex-activate-outline-and-hide-body ()
  (outline-minor-mode 1)
  (outline-hide-body) ;; fold all sections
)

(defun latex-activate-folding-and-hide-buffer ()
  (TeX-fold-mode 1)
  (TeX-fold-buffer) ;; fold envs and macros
)

(defun latex-neat-folding ()
  (interactive "@")
  (setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 1.3)
  (font-latex-update-sectioning-faces)
  (latex-activate-outline-and-hide-body)
  (latex-activate-folding-and-hide-buffer)
)
```

Surprisingly enough (to me - probably due to my limited understanding of hooks), this does not work if I add this function to latex's hook:

```lisp
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'latex-neat-folding)
```

Comment: The doc string of the variable `font-latex-fontify-sectioning` says: `...Setting
this variable directly does not take effect unless you call
‘font-latex-update-sectioning-faces’ or restart Emacs.` - did you do that?

Comment: I am aware. And yes, I did.

Comment: You did what exactly? Did you add the `setq` into your init file and restarted emacs? Or did you evaluate the `setq` in your current session and then evaluated `(font-latex-update-sectioning-faces)` in the same session? Or something else? In the first case, did you make sure that the `setq` was done before `font-latex` was loaded? You see, adding all these details to your question makes sure that we all understand the same thing: we have *NO* idea how much you know about emacs, so if you don't tell us all the details, we need to poke to find them all out. More detail is better than less...

Comment: FWIW, when I do the `setq` in my current emacs session and evaluate `(font-latex-update-sectioning-faces)` in the same session, the sizes reflect the setting (and 3.5 is much too big for comfort).

Comment: @NickD Sorry, I meant: yes, I added the `setq` to my init file and restarted Emacs.

Now I also tried it the other way: by setting the `font-latex-fontify-sectioning` to 3.5 in the scratch buffer and then running `(font-latex-update-sectioning-faces)` also in that buffer. Nothing changed in the latex buffer.

Comment: @NickD I found out that the problem is the interaction with fold-mode. I added the details to my question.